# Is it safe to put a password in a SIPS URI?

Tags: sip

A SIP or SIPS URI can contain an optional password field:

> sip:user:**password**@host:port;uri-parameters?headers

RFC 3261 says this about passwords in the URI:

> While the SIP and SIPS URI syntax allows this field to be present, its
>   use is NOT RECOMMENDED, because the passing of authentication
>   information in clear text (such as URIs) has proven to be a security
>   risk in almost every case where it has been used.

However, in SIPS, if the traffic is encrypted via TLS, then information is not passed in cleartext.   If so, why does the RFC not recommend using passwords in a SIPS URI?

Answer (score -2):

Security in depth. Usually you send a password in encrypted form. Then it goes through https which means it is encrypted again. To get the password, I need to crack https and the original encryption.

If you send the password in cleartext, then all I need to do is to convince your client to send the data in http, and steal the password. Or arrange a man-in-the-middle attack, and steal the password. Or crack https (which is rumoured to be doable if you have a hundred million dollars in spare cash, and there are organisations who have that money), or convince your client to use 40 bit encryption for https etc. etc.

Comment: Question was about SIP not HTTP.  While your response is valid from a security standpoint, I am asking about the particulars for SIPS.